# How to verify the text without stopping test execution in selenium RC

Tags: java, selenium-rc

I'm using selenium RC with Java. to verify the text present  i'm using below statement

```
com.unitedinternet.portal.selenium.utils.logging.LoggingAssert.assertEquals("Text not found",s.isElementPresent(CommanWebElements.lblOwner),true,(LoggingSelenium) s);
```

the problem is if the particular text is not present, execution will not be continued.how to use verify instead of assert in order to continue the execution if particular text is not present

Comment: unit testing is supposed to stop for a particular test case execution if there is an error. if the asserting is not important, i think you should not do it. When i used selinium, i used this assert equal to identify if i am on the right page or if a hidden field is visible. So Ideally you need to have different test methods for executing the remaining test cases

Comment: oK i got it.. but here my probelm is after performing some operation the text should not appear in the page.. i need to check it using selenium. so i used if(isTextPresent("Agency") . beacause of Agency is not present in the page if statement is giving false.. then assert is stopping execution.... so i need to use instead of assert .. please tess me how to use verifytext()

Comment: for doing some logic like that, i used waitForElementNotPresent() and then assertElementNotPresent() for the field. this was the method name in selinium plugin for FF. But can you tell me which jar name and version you are using for selenium RC. i happened to find [selenium RC 0.9.0](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/).

Comment: To verify text present or not fist get the text using get.text() and den compare them using "if" u'll get d result and u can even proceed with ur execution too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing some logic like that, i used `waitForElementNotPresent()` and then `assertElementNotPresent()` for the field. this was the method name in selinium plugin for FF. But can you tell me which jar name and version you are using for selenium RC. i happened to find [selenium RC 0.9.0](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.0/doc/java/)

i also found [selenium core](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/0.8.0/reference.html) link. this has all the methods i mentioned above. :). so i hope that solves your problem.